# customized error reporting in v4

Tags: antlr4

Another question on migrating code from v3 to v4:

For v3, I had a customized error reporting, using code like this (in the grammar file):

```
@members {
  public void displayRecognitionError(String[] tokenNames,
                                    RecognitionException e) {
    String hdr = getErrorHeader(e);
    String msg = getErrorMessage(e, tokenNames);
    System.out.println("ERR:"+hdr+":"+msg);
    errCount += 1;
  }
}
```

In v4, when compiling the generated java files, I am getting the error:

```
MyParser.java:163: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getErrorMessage(org.antlr.v4.runtime.RecognitionException,java.lang.String[])
location: class MyParser
            String msg = getErrorMessage(e, tokenNames);
                         ^
```

Is this function replaced by some other function in v4? (I saw some questions and answers on ANTLRErrorListener, but I could not get how to use it for my situation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `displayRecognitionError` method was removed in ANTLR 4, so even if you correct the body of that method it will not do anything. You need to remove the method from your grammar entirely, and implement [`ANTLRErrorListener`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRErrorListener.html) instead. The documentation includes a list of classes that implement the interface, so you can reference those and/or extend one of them to produce the desired functionality.

Once you have an instance of an `ANTLRErrorListener`, you can use the following code to attach it to a `Parser` instance.

```
// remove the default error listener
parser.removeErrorListeners();
// add your custom error listener
parser.addErrorListener(listener);
```